# In Apache, how do I set up password protection?

Tags: apache-2.2, password

I'm attempting to set up a server using Apache. In the conf file, I inserted the code:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Files"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile C:\...\serverpass.txt
    Require user Admin
</Directory>
```

In order to try and get Apache to require a password. I created the username and password with htpasswd -c. When I got to localhost though, it doesn't prompt me for a username and password?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7

Comment: Thanks all. I believe the problem was the <Directory c:/path/to/webroot/>, but I also made sure to restart and use '/' instead of '\'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/` isn't a path in Windows, so `<Directory />` won't do anything.

Consider using `<Location />` or `<Directory c:/path/to/webroot/>`?

Answer (score 2):

You did restart the apache webserver AFTER you made these changes?

Also, have you checked for conflicting directives in httpd.conf and all its include files. Remember the last overriding directive (and more specific directives) encountered wins the game and gets used.

Answer (score 2):

Try using "/" as path delimiter, not the windows-typical "\".

As it [says in the Apache docs](http://is.gd/thdV8T):

> The directives that accept filenames as arguments must use Windows
>   filenames instead of Unix ones. However, because Apache may interpret
>   backslashes as an "escape character" sequence, you should consistently
>   use forward slashes in path names, not backslashes. Drive letters can
>   be used; if omitted, the drive of the SystemRoot directive (or -d
>   command line option) becomes the default.

Answer (score 2):

```
<Directory />
```

The / here should be replaced with the specific directory where you are looking for authentication. Change it and restart the web server.

It sud work after that.